# Compare dictionaries to check if they are equal or if they go from empty to having a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, comparison

I have two dataframes where I am looping through each row and creating a dictionary for the rows that I am looking at to compare against each other.

I've done this by doing:

```
ids = []
for row in range(len(df1)-1):
    df1_row = dict(df1.iloc[row])
    df2_row = dict(df2.iloc[row])
    if df1_row == df2_row:
        ids.append(df1_row['ID'])
```

I am checking whether the two rows I am comparing at a time are equal and if they are I am appending the id from that row to a list to return at the end.

However I would also like to check the condition where if the row from df2 contains an empty string for a given key and the row from df1 contains a value for that same key, but the rest of the key-value pairs are equal between them, then I want to append that id to the list as well.

For example if I am looking at two rows like this

```
df1_row = {'NAME': 'Kelly', 'AGE': '15', 'CITY': 'London', 'GENDER': 'F', 'ID': 15}
df2_row = {'NAME': 'Kelly', 'AGE': '15', 'CITY': '', 'GENDER': 'F', 'ID': '15'}
```

Then I would like to append ID 15 to my list since CITY goes from EMPTY in df2_row to having a value in df1_row.

If the pair looked like this

```
df1_row = {'NAME': 'Kelly', 'AGE': '15', 'CITY': 'London', 'GENDER':''  'ID': 15}
df2_row = {'NAME': 'Kelly', 'AGE': '15', 'CITY': '', 'GENDER': 'F', 'ID': '15'}
```

I would not want to append id 15 to my resulting list since even though though CITY goes from EMPTY to having a value from df2_row to df1_row, GENDER goes form having a value to EMPTY from df2 to df1.

(Basically my checks are: the rows are exactly equal OR they have values that go from empty to non-empty (from df2 to df1) and the rest of the values are equal)

I tried doing

```
ids = []
for row in range(len(df1)-1):
    df1_row = dict(df1.iloc[row])
    df2_row = dict(df2.iloc[row])
    if df1_row == df2_row:
        ids.append(df1_row['ID'])
    else:
        for key in df1_row:
            if df1_row[key] == df2_row[key] or (df2_row[key] == '' and df1_row[key] != ''):
```

But I am not sure how to write the second condition so that it only appends the id after the whole row has been checked, rather than just check the condition on the current key-value and append the id right there...is there a way to check this condition for the entire row at once/another way to write this? Thanks! (or maybe there is just a better way to compare two rows in a dataframe for the same id against each other using these conditions without having to turn the rows into dictionaries to compare?)

TEST TABLES

DF1:

| NAME | AGE | CITY | GENDER | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kelly | 15 | London | F | 15 |
| Jack | 12 |  | M | 98 |
| Josh | 30 | Austin | M | 12 |

DF2:

| NAME | AGE | CITY | GENDER | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kelly | 15 |  | F | 15 |
| Jack |  | Munich | M | 98 |
| Josh | 30 | Austin | M | 12 |

I would want to get back IDs 15 and 12 because 12 matches exactly, and in 15 it matches exactly or it has a column value in df2 that goes to non empty in df1.

Comment: post a testable sample dataframes

Comment: posted two test dataframes

Comment: `has a column value in df2 that goes to non empty in df1` - any **single** column? If there are 2 empty columns in df2 but both have values in df1 does it meet your requirement? Why did you choose to turn each row into a dict first? [Series are dict-like](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#series-is-dict-like). Are the missing values empty strings or null or nan?

Comment: If any of the columns if df2 are empty and go to non-empty in df1 AND the other columns match on values that meets my requirement (so yes to if there are two empty column in df2 but they have values in df1), my case where i would not want to retain this id is if there is at least one column that goes from non-empty in df2 to empty in df1 (even with other values matching) OR  the rows all have values but do not match at all

Comment: The missing values are empty strings. I turned it into dictionaries because that was the only way I could think to compare the rows, so was not sure if there was a better method to achieve this

Comment: `isnull()` may be able to determine if the values changed to non-null between dataframes. After you have determined the value has changed to non-null then iterate the row to determine if the other values have changed. If the values have not changed then append the id, otherwise continue to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Set-up:

```py
# import pandas as pd 

## [ can just read tables from your question with: ]
## df1, df2 = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75688651')[:2]

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'NAME': 'Kelly', 'AGE': 15, 'CITY': 'London', 'GENDER': 'F', 'ID': 15}, {'NAME': 'Jack', 'AGE': 12, 'CITY': '', 'GENDER': 'M', 'ID': 98}, {'NAME': 'Josh', 'AGE': 30, 'CITY': 'Austin', 'GENDER': 'M', 'ID': 12}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'NAME': 'Kelly', 'AGE': 15.0, 'CITY': '', 'GENDER': 'F', 'ID': 15}, {'NAME': 'Jack', 'AGE': '', 'CITY': 'Munich', 'GENDER': 'M', 'ID': 98}, {'NAME': 'Josh', 'AGE': 30.0, 'CITY': 'Austin', 'GENDER': 'M', 'ID': 12}])
```

---

> *is there a way to check this condition for the entire row at once/another way to write this?*

You can use [`zip`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) and [`.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) with [`for...else`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) like:

```py
ids = []
for (i1,df1_row),(i2,df2_row) in zip(df1.fillna('').iterrows(),df2.fillna('').iterrows()): 
    for df1_val, df2_val in zip(df1_row, df2_row): 
        if not (df1_val==df2_val or df2_val==''): break
    else: ids.append(df2_row['ID'])
```

[With this `for...else`, it breaks if there are two unequal values where the `df2` value if not empty (and [`.fillna('')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) ensures that all `nan` values are replaced with `''` empty strings); if it never breaks (i.e., all values are equal *or* `df2` has the empty value), the `else` block will be executed and the `ID` will be added to `ids`.]

Instead of `for...else`, you can also use [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) with [`all`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all) to check every pair of values like you mentioned:

```py
checkPair = lambda df1_val, df2_val: df1_val==df2_val or df2_val=='' 
ids = [df2_row['ID'] for (i_1, df1_row), (i_2, df2_row) in zip(
    df1.fillna('').iterrows(), df2.fillna('').iterrows()
) if all(checkPair(v1, v2) for v1, v2 in zip(df1_row, df2_row))]
```

---

#### Suggested Solution:

> *or maybe there is just a better way to compare two rows in a dataframe for the same id against each other using these conditions without having to turn the rows into dictionaries to compare?*

Yes, pandas has the [`.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) method, which I thinks is quite handy for situations like this.

```py
comp_df = df1.set_index('ID').compare(df2.set_index('ID'), keep_shape=True)
```

As you can see from [comparison examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CInAq.png) (comparing `df1` to `df2`):

- `self` and `other` columns will [respectively] contain `df1` and `df2` values
- if both `df1` and `df2` have the same value, `self` and `other` will both contain `nan`

  - <sup>(unless you set `keep_equal=True`)</sup>
- so if you fill the `nan`s with `''`, you'll only need to check the `other` values

  - <sup>(view [**`comp_df.fillna('')`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMGSq.png?s=256) for demonstration)</sup>

So, using list comprehension and [`any`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any):

```py
ids = [i for i, r in comp_df.fillna('').iterrows() if not any(list(r!='')[1::2])]
```

or with `for...else`:

```py
comp_df = df1.set_index('ID').compare(df2.set_index('ID'), keep_shape=True)
colNames = {c[0] for c in comp_df.columns} # --> {'GENDER', 'AGE', 'CITY', 'NAME'}

ids = []
for i, row in comp_df.fillna('').iterrows():
    for c in colNames:
        if row[c]['other'] != '': break
    else: ids.append(i)
```

---

Any of the 4 methods above should result is `id` returning `[15, 12]`.

**Note that `.compare` requires both DataFrames to have the same exact shape and labels [for columns and indices].** [And the `for...zip...` methods from the first half will not work reliably unless all the columns and rows are sorted in the same order as well (e.g.: you can't have Jack before Kelly in `df2` as Kelly comes first in `df1`).]